# Syntax for `\NewDocumentCommand`

Tags: xparse

The `xparse` documentation gives examples of names of `\NewDocumentCommand`s enclosed in `braces`, and without `braces`, as demonstrated in the two commands below. Is there any difference in functionality whatsoever between the two? I never use braces and better be safe than sorry.

```
\documentclass{article}
%=======================
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\myExp{m}{#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\myExpAlt}{m}{#1}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
  \myExp{101}

  \myExpAlt{123}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In your example, there is no need for `\ExplSyntaxOn`...`\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Comment: Agreed, they are part of my MWE template as is `\usepackage[...]{expl3}` and I failed to remove them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference, similar to the notation used with `\newcommand` and friends, as long as you pass it a control sequence. Technically you're passing an argument to `\newcommand`, which is then set using `\def` internally, so you should use `{<csname>}`. However, if you don't use braces, the first token is grabbed.

Comment: Reassuring that there is no harm in not using braces, but formal correctness would dictate to use `{<csname>}`.